# Use Powershell to duplicate a directory's child names on a copy of a single JPG

Tags: file, powershell, copy, powershell-3.0, directory

I have a directory with 24 unique image files. Each image file has a unique and meaningful name. We are referencing the file names in a database, and rendering them on a website. I would like to replace each unique image with a JPG placeholder image. My idea is to create that JPG placeholder image, create 24 copies of it, and then give each copy one of the unique and meaningful names from the original directory.

After creating the placeholder image, I need the following PowerShell command:

```
Get the placeholder image.
For each legacy image in the legacy folder:
- Get its base name.
- Create a copy of the placeholder image.
- Name the placeholder copy with the legacy base name.
Done.
```

Anyway, it isn't that important - I thought it would be wonderful to do this with PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

Bingo!

```
Get-ChildItem '.\Legacy Items' -filter *.jpg | ForEach-Object `
{ `
    Copy-Item .\735x379.jpg .\Placeholders\$_ `
}
```

Note that the grave accent ` character lets us do a multi-line command in PowerShell.